# SQL, how can I create a lot of records for a reference join table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

At the moment, I'm using this, but its a little slow and I only end up with 1331 records. I'm thinking there must be a faster way to produce more records ?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS util_nums (n integer primary key 
  autoincrement not null);

insert into util_nums values (0);

insert into util_nums(n) select null from (select 0 as n union select 1 
union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 
union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 10) 
a cross join (select 0 as n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 
union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 
union select 9 union select 10) b cross join (select 0 as n union select 1 
union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 
union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 10) c;
```

I'm using sqlite

Comment: Why not just write your data to file and then import it into your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's much faster, but you can try

```
--assuming table is empty, insert 2 records
insert into util_nums values (null);
insert into util_nums values (null); 

insert into util_nums 
select null from     
util_nums,util_nums,util_nums,util_nums,util_nums,
util_nums,util_nums,util_nums,util_nums,util_nums,
util_nums,util_nums,util_nums,util_nums,util_nums,
util_nums,util_nums,util_nums,util_nums,util_nums
```

;
It inserts 2^20 (if you need more, just add another `util_nums` to `from`) + 2 records quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with all your data and then do a bulk insert into the table from the file.

[See this](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-bulk-insert-to-load-a-text-file)

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_util_nums
(
 n int NOT NULL,

)
go

DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
Declare @PathFileName varchar(max) 
SET @SQL = "BULK INSERT tmp_util_nums FROM '"+@PathFileName+"' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',') "
```

--Step 2: Execute BULK INSERT statement
    EXEC (@SQL)

--Step 3: INSERT data into final table
    INSERT into util_nums 
    SELECT  * FROM tmp_util_nums

```
TRUNCATE TABLE  tmp_util_nums
go
```